# tensorflow not recognising gpu in macbook pro 2019

Tags: macos, tensorflow, gpu

I have Macbook Pro 2019 with
GPU: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 645 1536 MB
I have created a virtual environment and installed Tensorflow and Tensorflow-metal
However when I code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices()
```

i get this output

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
```

tensorflow cannot find my gpu is there any way to use gpu on this mac?

Comment: Read https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/ in the section "Currently not supported".

Comment: installing a tensorflow-metal with pip solved this for me today.